# can't store data properly to implement the Breadth-first search in application like the oracle of bacon (object communication)

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I have .JSON file with objects that represent movies shown below. I'am trying to store the data in that file in a structure so i can use it in implementing the breadth-first search to build an application like (the oracle of bacon). I have Node objects and graph object to store all the nodes. I need to make a node for every movie and every actor. my problem is that the hasNode(node) -i made to only add the actor if i doesn't exist in the nodes of the graph- always returns false.

```
#sample JSON object:
{
            "title": "Diner",
            "cast": [
                "Steve Guttenberg",
                "Daniel Stern",
                "Mickey Rourke",
                "Kevin Bacon",
                "Tim Daly",
                "Ellen Barkin",
                "Paul Reiser",
                "Kathryn Dowling",
                "Michael Tucker",
                "Jessica James",
                "Colette Blonigan",
                "Kelle Kipp",
                "Clement Fowler",
                "Claudia Cron"
            ]}


function Graph() {
  this.nodes = [];
  this.graph = {};
}

Graph.prototype.addNode = function (node) {
  this.nodes.push(node);
}

Graph.prototype.hasNode = function (node) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
    if (this.nodes[i].name == node.name) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function Node(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.edges = [];
  this.searched = false;
  this.parent = null;
}

#My setup function:
var data;
var graph;

function preload() {
  data = loadJSON('kevinbacon.json');
}

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  graph = new Graph();
  var movies = data.movies;

  for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    var movie = new Node(movies[i].title);
    graph.addNode(movie);

    var cast = movies[i].cast;
    for (var j = 0; j < cast.length; j++) {
      var actor = new Node(cast[j]);
      if (!(graph.hasNode(actor))){
        graph.addNode(actor);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(graph);
}
```

i excpect the output to be the graph object with all the actors (not duplicated) and movies but i get it with actors duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that youre immediately returning even if the name doesnt equal in the first checked element .
Instead you should only abort if the name is found otherwise it wont check the rest of the names

```js
//sample JSON object:
var example=JSON.parse('{ "title": "Diner", "cast": [                "Steve Guttenberg",                "Daniel Stern",                "Mickey Rourke",                "Kevin Bacon",                "Tim Daly",                "Ellen Barkin",               "Paul Reiser",                "Kathryn Dowling",                "Michael Tucker",                "Jessica James",                "Colette Blonigan",                "Kelle Kipp",                "Clement Fowler",                "Claudia Cron"            ]}');


function Graph() {
  this.nodes = [];
  this.graph = {};
}

Graph.prototype.addNode = function (node) {
  this.nodes.push(node);
}

Graph.prototype.hasNode = function (node) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
    if (this.nodes[i].name == node.name) {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  return false
}

function Node(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.edges = [];
  this.searched = false;
  this.parent = null;
}

//My setup function:
var data;
var graph;


(function setup() {
  graph = new Graph();
  var movies = [example ];
  for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    var movie = new Node(movies[i].title);
    graph.addNode(movie);

    var cast = movies[i].cast;
    for (var j = 0; j < cast.length; j++) {
      var actor = new Node(cast[j]);
      if (!(graph.hasNode(actor))){
        console.log("adding node",actor)
        graph.addNode(actor);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(graph);
})();
```